# How to customize a QScrollBar

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qscrollbar

This image shows the kind of scrollbar I want in my Qt application:

[image: Wanted result]

And this is my attempt, which isn't close to the requirement:

```cpp
QString sbStyle = QString(
    "QScrollBar:vertical {"
    "border: none;"
    "background: #111;"
    "width: 10px;"
    "}"
    "QScrollBar::handle:vertical {"
    "background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 #ddd, stop:1 #111);"
    "min-height: 10px;"
    "}"
    "QScrollBar::add-line:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {"
    "border: none;"
    "background: #111;"
    "}"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Styling scroll bars (and complex widgets in general) requires some patience and proper studying of the documentation and the [examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar).

Most importantly, complex widgets have a fundamental requirement, as explained [in the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#sub-controls):

> **Note:** With complex widgets such as QComboBox and QScrollBar, if one property or sub-control is customized, all the other properties or sub-controls must be customized as well.

The most important issue with your attempt is that you didn't leave space for the buttons and did not set any stylesheet for them.

The space for the button is set by using proper margins (top and bottom for vertical scroll bars).

The arrow buttons can be styled using images, but for simple triangle shapes a smart CSS trick can be used: use borders.

The idea is to have an 0-sized object with borders around it; since only the borders are visible, the result is a rectangle composed of triangles, and the border width is actually the height of each triangle (the distance between the side and the center):

[image: 0-sized rectangle with borders]

Then you only draw the border that is opposed to the arrow direction; if you want to show an up arrow, draw the bottom border with a different color:

[image: up arrow using the bottom border]

Note tat in order to properly place those arrows without unnecessary margin (like the top "border" of the up arrow), some adjustments must be done using `top` or `bottom` properties.

Finally, if you need the dot-pattern background, that has to be done through an image (a simple 2x2 image will suffice).

Here is the resulting stylesheet:

```css
    QScrollBar:vertical {
        border: none;
        background: #111;
        width: 8px;
        margin: 6px 0 6px 0;
    }
    QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
        background: qlineargradient(
            x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, 
            stop:0 #fff, stop:1 #111
        );
        min-height: 8px;
        border: 2px solid;
        border-left-color: #ddd;
        border-top-color: #ddd;
        border-right-color: #444;
        border-bottom-color: #222;
    }
    QScrollBar::add-line:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
        border: none;
        background: #111;
        subcontrol-origin: margin;
        height: 6px;
    }
    QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
        subcontrol-position: bottom;
    }
    QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
        subcontrol-position: top;
    }
    QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
        border: 4px solid #111;
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
    }
    QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical {
        top: -2px;
        border-bottom-color: gray;
    }
    QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
        bottom: -2px;
        border-top-color: gray;
    }
    QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical:hover {
        border-bottom-color: lightgray;
    }
    QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical:hover {
        border-top-color: lightgray
    }
    QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
        background: url("pattern.png");
    }
    QScrollBar::add-page:vertical {
        background-position: bottom; /* prevent background "scrolling" */
    }
```

And here is the result:

[image: Screenshot of the result]

Zoomed in to see more details:

[image: Zoomed screenshot]

Comment: How to style qml scrollbar like exactly same.

Comment: QML doesn't use style sheets. I strongly suggest you to do proper research and patiently study the QML documentation, then **after attempting to do it on your own**, eventually post a new question showing those attempts and explaining what issues you have.